# Cannot subset the first column in a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Im learning how to use Pandas and I've downloaded some data from Kaggle about car prices etc.

I'm trying to create a new dataframe by subsetting all the cars out that have the model "Golf".

```
golfs = df[df.model == "Golf"]
```

It does return a new dataframe but when i call it, its just empty besides the column names.

trying this:

```
others = df[df.model != "Golf"]
```

creates a new dataframe, but it has everything in it. The datatype for the column is an object. So i tried to create subsets by transmission, which is also an object.

```
man_trans = df[df.transmission == "Manual"]
```

creates a new data frame with solely Manual transmissions... I have no idea where its going wrong. I've tried subsetting all other columns but its just the first one that wont behave. Ive even tried copying and pasting the cell value directly into the code.

Ive even tried adding in:

```
df.reset_index()
```

to add in a new index as i thought that might be the problem.

Comment: Try sum(df.model == "Golf"), I have a feeling you don't have any golfs - or at least you don't have any which exactly match the string "Golf". Maybe the field contains "golf" or "GOLF" or perhaps there's a space on the end ("Golf ")

Comment: Also try df.model.unique() to see what models exist

Comment: I've managed to create a scatterplot with all the models on so I can see which models I'd like compare. I made df.model.value_count() to see how many of each model type there are. Doing the same thing with a different model returns exactly the same results. Copying and pasting from the csv source does the same as manually typing it.

Comment: share the link to the kaggle dataset. let me look at the data. I agree with David. I think there should be some problem with the data or the way you loaded the data onto `df`

Comment: can you do df.head() and paste the output onto your question section. That will help us see sample data.

Comment: You know what I bet David's right about the space at the end! I'll apply a strip next time I'm at it and see what it does.

Comment: I've managed to load Colab onto my phone while I'm away. I quickly tried df.model.str.strip() and it returned just a single column. I've since done len(df.model.iloc[798]) which returns 5! So whitespace is the problem. I just added a space at the beginning and my subset finally works. Little lesson in data cleaning there. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks like it is correct to me. If the golf dataframe is empty, it is possible you dont have any rows where df['model'] == 'Golf'?. Maybe it's =="golf" instead?

```
# It this doesnt work....
# golfs = df[df.model == "Golf"]
# Maybe try this (or something like this
golfs = df[df.model == "golf"]
```

Answer (score 0):

So David was totally correct with the space, but it wasnt at the end it was at the beginning. I checked what David was saying by applying:

'''

len(df.model.iloc[798])

'''

To find out how many characters were in a cell to what I was looking for. "Golf" only has 4 but 5 was being returned.

'''

df.model = df.model.str.lstrip()
len(df.model.iloc[798])
4

'''

Thanks to the people that responded and helped me find an answer to this stupidly simple problem.